# How to access nested array of objects in mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pipeline

I have a document like this(this is the result after few pipeline stages)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e9d5785e4c8343bb2b455cc"),
    "name": "Jenny Adams",
    "report": [
      { "category":"Beauty", "status":"submitted", "submitted_on": [{"_id": "xyz", "timestamp":"2022-02-23T06:10:05.832+00:00"}, {"_id": "abc", "timestamp":"2021-03-23T06:10:05.832+00:00"}] },
      { "category":"Kitchen", "status":"submitted", "submitted_on": [{"_id": "mnp", "timestamp":"2022-05-08T06:10:06.432+00:00"}] }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e9d5785e4c8343bb2b455db"),
    "name": "Mathew Smith",
    "report": [
      { "category":"Household", "status":"submitted", "submitted_on": [{"_id": "123", "timestamp":"2022-02-23T06:10:05.832+00:00"}, {"_id": "345", "timestamp":"2021-03-23T06:10:05.832+00:00"}] },
      { "category":"Garden", "status":"submitted", "submitted_on": [{"_id": "567", "timestamp":"2022-05-08T06:10:06.432+00:00"}] },
      { "category":"BakingNeeds", "status":"submitted", "submitted_on": [{"_id": "891", "timestamp":"2022-05-08T06:10:06.432+00:00"}] }
    ]
  }
]
```

I  have user input for time period -

```
from - 2021-02-23T06:10:05.832+00:00
to - 2022-02-23T06:10:05.832+00:00
```

Now I wanted to filter the objects from the report which lie in a certain range of time, I want to  only keep the object if the `"submitted_on[-1]["timestamp"]"` is in range of *from* and *to* date timestamp.
I am struggling with accessing the timestamp because of the nesting
I tried this

```
$project: {
  "name": 1,
  "report": {
    "category": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "submitted_on": 1,
    "timestamp": {
      $arrayElemAt: ["$report.cataloger_submitted_on", -1]
    }
  }
}
```

But this gets the last object of the report array `{"_id": "bcd", "timestamp":"2022-05-08T06:10:06.432+00:00"}` for all the items inside the report. How can I do this to select the last timestamp of each obj.

Comment: Would you show what you expect as output?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your phase in the aggregation pipeline with two phases: `$unwind` and `$addFields` in order to get what I think you want:

```
  {
    $unwind: "$report"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "timestamp": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$report.submitted_on",
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

The `$unwind` phase is breaking the external array into documents since you want to perform an action on each one of them. See the playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CXMcSozaM1C) with your example. If you plan to continue the aggregation pipeline with more steps, you can probably skip the `$addFields` phase and include the condition inside your next `$match` phase.